# Issue in document insert using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have schema created now i want to insert into mongodb collection, but its throwing error `diagramModel.insert` is not defined any idea what is implemented wrong ?

app.js

```
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/develop-modeler');
require('./server/api/diagram/diagram.model.js');
var diagramModel = mongoose.model('Diagram');
var newDiagram = {
      "owner" : "sh529u",
      "text" : "sco_poc.bpmn",
      "users":["wp6307","kz323j","ew6980"],
      "groups":[],
      "string" : "test"
      }
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
  diagramModel.insert(newDiagram,function(err,res){
     if (err) { console.log(err);}
     else {
     diagramModel.find({}, function(err, data) { console.log(data);});
    }
  });

});
```

diagram.model.js

```
var DiagramSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  owner: {type: String, ref:'User'},
  groups: [{type: String, ref: 'Group'}],
  users: [{type: String, ref: 'User'}],
  string: String
});

mongoose.model('Diagram', DiagramSchema);
```

Comment: I think you meant "Schema" instead of "Shema" in your title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's `save` not `insert` while saving records. That's why you are getting this error

```
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/develop-modeler');
 var diagramModel = require('./server/api/diagram/diagram.model.js');
 var newDiagram = {
   "owner": "sh529u",
   "text": "sco_poc.bpmn",
   "users": ["wp6307", "kz323j", "ew6980"],
   "groups": [],
   "string": "test"
 }
 mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
   diagramModel.save(newDiagram, function(err, res) {
     if (err) {
       console.log(err);
     } else {
       diagramModel.find({}, function(err, data) {
         console.log(data);
       });
     }
   });
 });



var DiagramSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  owner: {type: String, ref:'User'},
  groups: [{type: String, ref: 'Group'}],
  users: [{type: String, ref: 'User'}],
  string: String
});
module.exports=mongoose.model('Diagram', DiagramSchema);
```

Comment: Now i am getting `diagramModel.save` is not a function

Comment: You didn't export your model

Comment: DiagramSchema is in diagram.model.js  so i added export there but i still see error diagramModel.save is not a functions

Comment: what this line does `var diagramModel = mongoose.model('Diagram');`

Comment: it's not a proper way to require any custom module?

Comment: You did something wrong try to require proper model

Comment: I updated my answer with proper way required your model, now it'll work

Comment: Ohh,, remove `new` keyword from schema and then try

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working perfect

```
 var diagramModel = require('./server/api/diagram/diagram.model.js');

   var finalDiagram = diagramModel({
                      "owner" : "sh529u",
                      "text" : "sco_poc.bpmn",
                      "users":["wp6307","kz323j","ew6980"],
                      "groups":[],
                      "string" : "test"
                      });

 mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
  finalDiagram.save(function (err, dataObj) {
          if (err) { console.log(err);}
         } else {
             console.log("DATA",dataObj);
                diagramModel.find({}, function(err, data) { console.log(data);});

    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of your model and this instance contains a `save` method:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/develop-modeler');
require('./server/api/diagram/diagram.model.js');
var diagramModel = mongoose.model('Diagram');
var newDiagram = new diagramModel({
      "owner" : "sh529u",
      "text" : "sco_poc.bpmn",
      "users":["wp6307","kz323j","ew6980"],
      "groups":[],
      "string" : "test"
});
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
  newDiagram.save(function(err,res){
     if (err) { console.log(err);}
     else {
     diagramModel.find({}, function(err, data) { console.log(data);});
    }
  });

});
```